# How do you clear a tree in ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have managed to create an [Ext.tree.TreePanel](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.tree.TreeNode) that loads child nodes dynamically, but I'm having a difficult time clearing the tree and loading it with new data.  Can someone help me with the code to do this?

Answer (score 6):

From the wonderful blog of Saki an ExtJS guru.

```
while (node.firstChild) {
    node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
}
```

http://blog.extjs.eu/know-how/how-to-remove-all-children-of-a-tree-node/

Answer (score 4):

In Ext JS 4:

if you want to reload the data of the tree panel, you need to reload the tree store:

```
getCmp('treeId').getStore().load();
```

where treeId is the id of the tree. If you have a store id, you may directly use load() on store id.

to remove all child nodes:

```
getCmp('treeId').getRootNode().removeAll();
```

However, removing child nodes is not necessary for reloading the tree nodes from its store.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, my Ext tree has a hidden root node of type AsyncTreeNode. If I want to clear the tree and repopulate from the server, it's pretty simple:

```
tree.getRootNode().reload();
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found an answer in their forums.  For anyone interested it is here:

```
if (tree)
{
    var delNode;
    while (delNode = tree.root.childNodes[0])
        tree.root.removeChild(delNode);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use `node.removeAll()` to remove all child nodes from this node.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-removeAll

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and the solution i came up with was to 'tag' the node has having not loaded when it was collapsed thus forcing a reload when it was re-expanded.

```
listeners: {
   collapsenode: function(node){
   node.loaded = false;
},
```

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> if (tree) { var delNode; while (delNode = tree.root.childNodes[0]) tree.root.removeChild(delNode); }
> ```

I don't know Ext, but I'm guessing that they have DOM abstraction that might make that easier. An equivalent in Prototype would be something like:

```
tree.root.immediateDescendants().invoke('remove'); // or
tree.root.select('> *').invoke('remove');
```

Unless `tree.root` refers to a collection object rather than the tree's root DOM node, but is borrowing DOM API method names? That seems really unlikely, especially for a modern JS library.